# Which one is correct to say "Hello everyone": 大家好 or 你好大家?

Tags: sentence

When you want to say hello to many people in front of you,
which one is correct to say "Hello everyone": 大家好 or 你好大家?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While `大家` does mean 'everyone', it functions like the 2nd person *plural* pronoun ('you all') here. In `*你好大家`, there are two problems:

- With `你` always being the 2nd person *singular* pronoun, the **plurality** is confusing.
- Even if you say it like `*你們好大家` to match the plurality, there is much **redundancy**. It is ungrammatical and nonsensical to add a subject (`大家`) *after* a topic–comment (`你們好`) sentence.

Much better if you say `大家好` or `你們好` instead. `大家` is friendlier than `你們`.

Answer (score 3):

**大家好** can be found in multiple dictionaries and reference materials. Here is one such example:

*Adsotrans*

> 大家好
> dàjiā hǎo
>
> PHRASE OTHR
> hello everyone

你好大家 does not seem to have been recorded in any reference books and just sounds like poorly translated English.